# Order the variables geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

My data frame is as follow:

```
thin50 <- structure(list(yta = c(1102L, 1102L, 1102L, 1103L, 1103L, 1105L, 
    1105L, 1105L, 1107L, 1107L, 1107L, 1108L, 1108L, 1108L, 1109L, 
    1109L, 1110L, 1110L, 1110L, 1113L, 1113L, 1102L, 1102L, 1102L, 
    1103L, 1103L, 1105L, 1105L, 1105L, 1107L, 1107L, 1107L, 1108L, 
    1108L, 1108L, 1109L, 1109L, 1110L, 1110L, 1110L, 1113L, 1113L, 
    1102L, 1102L, 1102L, 1103L, 1103L, 1105L, 1105L, 1105L, 1107L, 
    1107L, 1107L, 1108L, 1108L, 1108L, 1109L, 1109L, 1110L, 1110L, 
    1110L, 1113L, 1113L), avd = c(6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
    2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
    2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
    3L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L), beh = c("50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", 
    "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", "UN", "UN", 
    "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", 
    "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", "UN", 
    "UN", "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", 
    "UN", "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", 
    "UN", "UN", "50%", "UN", "50%", "50%", "UN", "50%", "UN"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Htveg", 
    "dod", "sumut"), class = "factor"), value = c(313, 299.6, 353.7, 
    267.8, 392.9, 191.3, 191.4, 353.4, 238, 226.2, 419.6, 273, 410, 
    370.6, 317, 515.1, 142.5, 160, 341, 324.5, 447.9, 12.7, 22.6, 
    101.6, 32.5, 38.9, 17.1, 24.8, 0, 5.2, 10.6, 12.3, 13.5, 29.5, 
    34.4, 13.9, 19.4, 26.2, 28, 7.6, 15.6, 44.5, 89.6, 92.6, 0, 86.4, 
    0, 100.4, 119.9, 0, 121.1, 112.9, 0, 90.1, 0, 0, 59.6, 0, 79.6, 
    83.1, 0, 115.3, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -63L), .Names = c("yta", 
    "avd", "beh", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

I do a bar plot:

```
ggplot(aes(x = paste(yta, beh, sep = ":"), y = value, fill = variable), data = thin50) + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_grey() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        text = element_text(size=14, color = "black", vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "Experiment : treatment", y = expression(m^3) )
```

And I get this figure:

[image]

How I can change the order of the y-axis that darker-grey is upon lighter-grey?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the order of the stacking you need to change the order of the factor levels first, e.g.:

```
thin50$variable <- factor(thin50$variable, levels=c("Htveg", "sumut", "dod"))
```

It's not entirely clear to me if you want the colours to remain in the same order or if they should stay the same for the factor levels, so you can either keep  `scale_fill_grey()` or add `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
ggplot(aes(x = paste(yta, beh, sep = ":"), y = value, fill = variable), data = thin50) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "stack") +
  #scale_fill_grey() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "lightgrey", "darkgrey")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        text = element_text(size=14, color = "black", vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "Experiment : treatment", y = expression(m^3))
```

[image]

Comment: That would make sense. I was having trouble understanding the request. Good job.

Comment: Thanks for all your attempts. I visualized what I really want, see the edited post. It is sth with the shift of the levels of variable but I can not make it. When I tried all changed into `NA`

Comment: @beetroot can U check which `ggplot2` version U have

Comment: @Mateusz1981 I'm using 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

If you mean switch the colouring:

Add the following:

```
+ scale_fill_grey(start=.6, end=.1)
```

In the following way:

```
ggplot(aes(x = paste(yta, beh, sep = ":"), y = value, fill = variable), data = thin50) + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_grey() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        text = element_text(size=14, color = "black", vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "Experiment : treatment", y = expression(m^3) ) +
  scale_fill_grey(start=.6, end=.1)
```

Output:

[image]

If you mean to simply turn the graph upside-down on the y-axis without altering colours or values you can add:

```
+ scale_y_reverse()
```

As follows:

```
ggplot(aes(x = paste(yta, beh, sep = ":"), y = value, fill = variable), data = thin50) + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_grey() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        text = element_text(size=14, color = "black", vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "Experiment : treatment", y = expression(m^3) ) +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

Output:

[image]

I'm no longer getting a response on chat so I don't know if this is what you want.

But here is the graph with the bars spaced out:

[image]

This was achieved with this code:

```
ggplot(thin50,aes(x = paste(yta, beh, sep = ":"), y = value, fill=factor(variable))) + #stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_grey() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), # this line is not needed. Only included as a fix for legend/key random line
        legend.position = "none",
        text = element_text(size=14, color = "black", vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(.9), stat="identity", colour="black")  +
  labs(x = "Experiment : treatment", y = expression(m^3) )
```

The important bit of code above is:

```
+ geom_bar(position=position_dodge(.9), stat="identity", colour="black")
```

There is some overlapping bars still but that is because you haven't averaged everything & therefore there are duplicate variables. If you use the aggregate function it will take care of this redundancy.

Comment: It is not what I meant. I wanted to send this lighter down with the value not just change the colurs

Comment: @Mateusz1981 Can you find an example graph online?

Comment: I do not think I understand. But the thing is to leave black as it is and shift two others (both colors and values).

Comment: @Mateusz1981 It's very unclear what you want the graph to look like. If you could search for a graph on Google that has the look/style you want and post the link here I can probably help you.

Comment: The one thing I want is to send the dark-grey to the top and lighter gray to the middle of the graph. This will not change the graph but the order of the variables within the bar will change.

Comment: @Mateusz1981 I'm guessing my last edit is not what you want then?

Comment: No it is not. If you take the first bar (single one that shows value just over 400 m3). The result I want to have is: black as it is (350m3) than light-grey (50m3) and than dark-grey (10m3).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106004/discussion-between-docconcoct-and-mateusz1981).